# How to find how many week in particular month and year using mysql, I have only year and month no date

Tags: mysql

How to find how many week in particular month and year using mysql, I have only year and month no date value.

Example find out number of week year = 2017 and month = August

I search many times but all examples are given with date.

Comment: How about `weekNum(lastDayOfMonth) - weekNum(firstDayOfMonth) + 1` ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week